# Unable to run projects on netbeans-8

Tags: java, netbeans

I have just installed Netbeans8.0 and JDK 8.0 but i am facing three problems:

**1.** When I try to run my previous Netbeans-7.4 projects on netbeans 8 it gives this error:

```
GlassFish Server 4.0, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false
C:\Users\admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Netbeans8project\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1048:   
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

**2.** It is giving this error when i try to see library after right clicking the project:

```
Missing library-hibernate support
```

**3.** When I am creating a new project it is not showing Java8 in the Java EE version.

I have googled these problems and triedfew solutions but I am unable to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** You have to [add your GlassFish Server to Netbeans](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1770/gioew/index.html).

**2.** You have to add "Hibernate" and "Java EE Base" Plugin to Netbeans. Tools -> Plugins -> Available Plugins -> search for Hibernate.

**3**. Should be fixed if **2.** is done.

Comment: Is the Server started? Are there any errors when starting GlassFish Server in console? Something like this: `GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (89) startup time : Felix (1.757ms), startup services(3.184ms), total(4.941ms)`

Comment: No actually when i run a project it says in log `starting glassfish server` and after 20 minutes it prints the error `glassfish server failed build stopped`.

Comment: Could you please start the Server in the tab "Services" and post the output? Services -> Servers -> GlassFish Server (right-click -> Start).

Comment: What about **2.** and **3.**?

Comment: 3rd is fixed and i think 2nd is also resolved.Posting glassfish output in just a minute.

Comment: Hey man all problems are resolved actually i reinstalled my Netbeans 8.But for your effort i am accepting your answer.Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Hey man one last question i am writing my code on java 8 but there is one problem when i right click my project and click on run there is written `Java EE Version: Java EE 7 Web`.I don't know why?in the sources i have selected Java 8 but i don't know why can't i run my application on java 8

Comment: Also when i am creating a new project it is not showing java 8 under server and settings

Comment: You actually installed JDK 8.*. The Java EE Verson is 7 at the moment.  This means: A java project will run on JDK 8. A java **web** project will run on Java EE 7 Web.

Comment: Ok my bad.i got confused.So actually Oracle have released JDK 8 not Java EE Verson 8. Any idea when could we get Java EE Version 8 in the future

Comment: I don´t know. But here (https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/Home) they are talking about _Planning for Java EE 8 is now well underway._